# How to update my dropdown list without reloading the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got a dropdown list where a user can select an option.  The functionality works as it should but the page reloads each time. I've done a bunch of reading and seen examples but I'm having a hard time synthesizing the methods I've seen.  I know I have to pass AJAX on a format.js call in the controller method like:

```
def update_device_position
...
if @cabinet.add_cabinet_item(@position_str,params[:position].to_i)
  format.js
```

Then in the view, I have to add form_tag code like something like this:

```
            <div id="add_device">
                <%= form_tag(:url => {:action => url_for(:controller => "cabinets", :action => :update_device_position), :position => i , :id => @cabinet.id }, remote: true)%>
                <td>
                    <%= select_tag :position_name, options_for_select(@selection_list) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= hidden_field_tag 'position', i %>
                    <%= submit_tag "Add" , :class => "btn" %>
                </td>

            </div>
```

When I select the new value for the cabinet slot and click submit, I get a routing error stating `No route matches [POST] "/cabinets/99999999"`

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use a `form_tag(url: {[blabla..]}, remote: true)` to create a form submitable via Ajax

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I added your recommendation and I think I'm a bit closer.  When I try to submit on the change, I get the following message.  `No route matches [POST] "/cabinets/99999999"`?  Do you know how I can configure the routes properly?  Or is it my format.js call that's incorrect?